# Conditionally update column from another column in same table

Tags: mysql

I've looked through SO, and there are similar questions, but I can't seem to figure out how to do what I need.

For the purposes of this question, my table has 3 columns: `reconciled` (tinyint), `datereconciled` (timestamp, CAN BE NULL), and `dateadded` (timestamp).

For my code logic, if `reconciled`==1, there should be a timestamp in `datereconciled`, but I recently noticed that wasn't always happening.  Fixed the code, but now have a lot of NULL values in `datereconciled` where there should be a timestamp.  So, for all rows where `reconciled`==1 AND `datereconciled`==NULL, I would like to "update" the value FROM `dateadded` INTO `datereconciled`.  If there is already a timestamp in `datereconciled`, leave it alone.  And leave it alone if `reconciled`==0.

Comment: Can you share sample input tables, expected output and your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a simple update:

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET DateReconciled = DateAdded 
WHERE DateReconciled IS NULL 
AND reconciled = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically wrote the query already

```
UPDATE table SET datereconciled = dateadded 
WHERE reconciled = 1
AND datereconciled IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured I'd have to use a select in my update query, so I'm a victim of over-complicating things! However, here is my overly complicated self-discovered answer prior to the answers provided:

```
UPDATE
    `transactions` AS `dest`,
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `transactions`
        WHERE
            `reconciled` = 1 AND `datereconciled` IS NULL
    ) AS `src`
SET
    `dest`.`datereconciled` = `src`.`dateadded`
;
```

Comment: Your code is obviously wrong: https://dbfiddle.uk/RmHP4gDk